# NGINX Folder to ROOT redirect / rewrite

Tags: php, nginx

My question is the following:
i want to redirect 301 from a folder to root

https://www.mydomain.de/shop
to

https://www.mydomain.de/

with .htacces i would create a 301 redirect.
how do i do it with NGINX
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add this rules in server block:

```
location ~ /shop/ {
            rewrite ^ https://$host permanent;
    }
```